# Mirror и Unity. Как начать работать?

Tags: unity3d

Решил таки добраться до мультиплеера, хотя бы играть с друзьями через wi-fi. Остановил свой выбор на использовании Mirror. Однако, никак не могу понять, как начать с ним работать. Как создается сервер, как его искать тем, кто подключается к точке доступа wi-fi, как создавать объекты и передавать через сервер хотя бы сообщения с цифрами?

Comment: https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/general/getting-started

Comment: Документацию на английском я тоже нашел... Вот бы кто подробно объяснил, как именно взаимодействуют клиенты с сервером (или хостом). Например, я сейчас создаю на общей панели при нажатии клавиши текстовый префаб и вношу туда текст с временем нажатия данной клавиши. Однако, у меня то эти префабы отображаются только на хосте, при нажатии клавиши на хосте создаются несколько префабов, при этом, время, которое прописано на самом хосте - одно, а у клиентов - другое!